# django-compressor Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: django, django-compressor

This is my JS structure:
[image]

This is the beginning index.js

```
import { elements } from './views/base';
const state = {};
const controlRandomPhrasal = async () => {}
```

My base.js:

```
export const elements = {
    searchFrom: document.querySelector('.search'),
}
```

I invoke the compressor like this:

```
{% compress js %}
  <script src="{% static "phrasals/js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static "phrasals/js/index.js" %}"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

How can I configure my project to avoid that error?
Or can you suggest me an easier/better bundler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of being looking for a response. I choose to build my pipeline using Webpack and Babel. This is where I started:
[Hybrid application, Django-Webpack](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/integrating-javascript-pipeline/)